# Commenting on "First Post" review test always leads to a penalty

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-post-review

I was reviewing first posts today and got this test question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18497352 ([represented by this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899289/array-pointer-data-being-cleared-in-between-function-calls-without-an-explicit-c))

Because the output was included as images, I just wanted to let the poster know that they should include all output as text if possible. Instead I was tested negative. Maybe this question should get removed from the review tests or commenting on it should not count as a failure?